# Do skew lines in $\mathcal{R}^3$ intersect in a complex position?

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

(By a complex position I mean a position vector whose Cartesian coordinates are complex.)

I guess the simple answer is “no”, as any intersections (of which there can be none, one, or infinitely many) are real.

But I am wondering if there is some set of equations which is solved by a real position for intersecting lines, and by a complex position for skew lines(?).

Ideally, that complex position has some meaning. For example, if P and Q are the points on the two lines that are closest to the other line, it would be magic if the real part of that complex position is (P+Q)/2.

Comment: Interesting question. I have no answer.  In case it has some interest for you, [here](http://www.pdmi.ras.ru/~olegviro/skewlines.pdf) is a good (and deep) paper on skew lines.

Comment: Thank you, @MorganRodgers.  I will try what you suggest.  I think I somehow need to create a quadratic equation to get complex solutions... maybe your approach works.  Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks very much, @JeanMarie.  I will complete the "Light reading for the professional" task you set me :)  Thanks again!

Comment: I will think again to it. It should be possible in the spirit of a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2611435) I have asked  2 years ago.